# Software for bulk image editing

Tags: windows, gratis, images, image-editor

I am looking for a free software (preferably open-source) for Windows, which is able to take a folder full of images as an input and edit those in bulk.

Features should be for example things like reducing the pixe-size by x%, converting to another format, etc.

Maybe something like http://www.imagemagick.org but in a GUI.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows I have to recommend [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/). Their website is pretty ancient, but the software is reliable and the batch functions work for everything I've ever needed them for.

1. Install IrfanView and be sure you also have the extra plugin file.
2. Open IrfanView and press <kbd>T</kbd> to show the IrfanView thumbnail screen.
3. Browse to the folder that contains the files that you want to convert.
4. Select the files that you want to convert. Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to select multiple files.
5. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the conversion dialog screen.
6. Make the appropriate changes.

   - Choose whether to convert, rename, or both.
   - Rename the files.
   - Select a directory to save the files in.
7. Press the *Start Batch* button.

Answer (score 4):

For Free and Open Source image manipulation, you can never go wrong with [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

For editing images in bulk (Batch Processing), I would suggest getting the [BIMP](http://www.alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/) plugin for GIMP.

Plugin installation is simple, just download and run the installer from on their site, and you should be able to batch process images in GIMP by just going to `File -> Batch Image Manipulation...` and add the effects you want applied.

Both GIMP and BIMP are free and open source.